# Meaning of ってのも/というのも

Tags: grammar

> ひとりで夕陽の中を走るバカってのもねぇ～
>   Idiots who run alone towards the setting sun ...

The sentence seems to be lacking a verb. What is the function of ってのも and is there an implied verb ending?

I read [this link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33715/why-is-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF-used-both-times-in-this-sentence) which matches my expectations on というのは to provide a defintion. I can't extrapolate from that to the meaning of ってのも in this sentence。It also seems quite different to the use in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38580/understanding-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82) that I asked a while ago:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

～というのもね (and variants such as "～っていうのもねぇ", "～ってのもな～") at the end of a sentence is fairly common in speech. Such a sentence is usually euphemistically saying "～というのも問題でしょう", "～というのもあまり良くない", etc.

Likewise, if you encounter a verb-lacking sentence like "彼もねぇ……。" or "今回のオリンピックもなぁ……。", you can usually assume something negative is implied.